# Where and How do I install django framework on a server?

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I'm new to Django and still learning.

Currently I have server set up with the follow folders:
'www'
'db'
'private'

Where and How do I install django framework on a server? 
It can be accessed with ftp and ssh.

Currently. I just know that php works and loads within the www folder.
Do I have to install python?

Thanks everybody in advance.

Comment: I applaud your interest in learning Django. However just a note of caution. Django is a little more tricky to setup and deploy properly and securely compared to PHP, so even if you setup Django on server, please do not fully deploy it until you are absolutely sure it will not compromise your security, or at least you will be much more comfortable using Django.

Comment: Recently, there was a kickstarter project for a video series for getting started with Django. It should be out soon. I would recommend to watch it as soon it comes out. It will help you in many ways learning Django. http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a good practice to use a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) such as `virtualenv`. After you install `virtualenv` and activate it, you can then install django via `pip install django` which will install Django to your `virtualenv`. An easy way to organize the package requirements is to put the package you will use in a `requirements.txt` file, which looks like something like this:

```
Django==1.4.1
Mako==0.7.0
MarkupSafe==0.15
```

You can then install all the required packages with `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`

---

Setting up Django for deployment:

1. [Cleanest & Fastest server setup for Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025/cleanest-fastest-server-setup-for-django)
2. official django doc [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/) and [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/)
3. [Basic Django deployment with virtualenv, fabric, pip and rsync](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2010/04/22/basic-django-deployment-with-virtualenv-fabric-pip-and-rsync/)